# WPF Printing from a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am having trouble printing from a TextBox in WPF

My Textbox will only contain a number between 1 and 999

I wanted to print font size 72 and the text enclosed within a 4" box (so they can cut around the edges)

```
    private void InvokePrint(String contentToPrint)
    {
        // Create the print dialog object and set options
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        pDialog.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
        pDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

        // Display the dialog. This returns true if the user presses the Print button.
        Nullable<Boolean> print = pDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (print == true)
        {
            FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            pDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator, "Printing Label");
        }
    }
```

I got the code from Microsoft's site but they are using an XPS printer. I want to use the default selected printer (usually an HP).

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Check this post, you would need to detect the default printer or spedfify one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86138/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-default-printer-in-net

Comment: I know how to get the printer name. I dont know how 2 send the print job to the printer.

Comment: The user controls this via the print dialog.

Comment: What is your problem?
You don't want to show printer dialog or smth else?